# Return when reading from a file python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, return, return-value, return-type

I need to return the result of reading from the file, but when using the return, one value is read and the action stops.

```
        with open("DJ.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(content, file)
            print('Запись прошла успешно')
            file.close()

        with open("DJ.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            return data
```

20 lines of text are written to the file, but when reading I get only one.

I read that i can use yield, but I can’t understand how, please help.

Comment: can you share the file content?is this code part of function?

Comment: A file you can find here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn0ev9hjbgl9b0f/DJ.json?dl=0

Comment: Code part function, function write to file and read from the file

Comment: this file content is well formatted json

Comment: Yes, but when i return data, only the first line is return, if i print data i print all lines, how i can return all lines?